# SAS: Importing CSV file with dates

Tags: csv, sas

I am currently trying to import a zipped csv file into SAS and I have 3 columns with dates written in the format YYYY-MM-DD. All data in this csv file is in unique lines, so I assume that it is a string and not recognised as numbers (sorry I only started coding recently and I am still learning a lot of basics).
What happens is that SAS assumes 8 characters and it comes up with 2010-08-, basically missing the day. 
I tried several ways to get around that using input, but so far without solving it. I either get an empty column or one with the conversion numbers (such as 52789 - I guess that is from that 1960 date SAS is using as a reference)
I hope you guys can give me some hints how to get this done.
The code is:

```
FILENAME IPC3data zip 'C:\Users\********\IPC3data.zip'
member='tls201_appln.csv';
DATA newdata;
  INFILE IPC3data DLM=';' DSD FIRSTOBS=2;
  INPUT appln_id $ appln_auth $ appln_nr $ appln_kind $ appln_filing_date $ appln_filing_year $ appln_nr_epodoc $ appln_nr_original $ ipr_type $ internat_appln_id $ int_phase $ reg_phase $ nat_phase $ earliest_filing_date $ earliest_filing_year $ earliest_filing_id $ earliest_publn_date $ earliest_publn_year $ earliest_pat_publn_id $ granted $ docdb_family_id $ inpadoc_family_id $ docdb_family_size $ nb_citing_docdb_fam $ nb_applicants $ nb_inventors;
 Filing_date = input(appln_filing_date, ANYDTDTE10.);
 put Filing_date=YYMMDD10.;
 Early_filing_date = input(earliest_filing_date, ANYDTDTE10.);
 put Early_filing_date=YYMMDD10.;
 Early_publn_date = input(earliest_publn_date, ANYDTDTE10.);
 put Early_publn_date=YYMMDD10.;
```

RUN;
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your variables, then you will not have truncation issues.

Personally I find it much easier to define the variables first in the order that I want to read them by using a LENGTH statement.  Here is one that is the equivalent of how SAS would have guessed at how to define your variables based on your current INPUT statement, but I have changed all of the ..._date variable to be 10 character strings instead of the default 8 characters.  You probably should change the length (or even the type) of some of the other variables also.

```
LENGTH appln_id appln_auth appln_nr appln_kind $8 appln_filing_date $10
       appln_filing_year appln_nr_epodoc appln_nr_original $8
       ipr_type internat_appln_id int_phase reg_phase nat_phase $8
       earliest_filing_date $10 earliest_filing_year earliest_filing_id $8
       earliest_publn_date $10 earliest_publn_year earliest_pat_publn_id $8
       granted docdb_family_id inpadoc_family_id docdb_family_size $8
       nb_citing_docdb_fam nb_applicants $8
       nb_inventors 8
;
```

Then the INPUT statement can be very simple because you can use a positional variable list by putting a `--` between the first and last variable names.

```
input appln_id -- nb_inventors ;
```

But in reality dates are numbers in SAS.  You just need to use special informats and formats so that SAS knows how to translate from and to human readable text strings.  So change your date variables to numbers by changing the length from `$10` to `8` and attach an appropriate informat and SAS will store them as dates instead of character strings.

```
informat appln_filing_date earliest_filing_date earliest_publn_date yymmdd.;
format appln_filing_date earliest_filing_date earliest_publn_date yymmdd10.;
```

Comment: Dear Tom, thanks for the length comment - that solved the problem! U R right, I also need more than 8 spaces for some id columns too. The -- trick I knew but didnt think about it...however, if I add the informat/format part, it always gives me an error statement "The informat $yymmdd. was not found or could not be loaded." Not sure if I still need to add this given that the length statement gave me full dates?

Comment: You must use an informat that matches the type of the variable. Since your variable was character SAS is looking for an informat that will generate a character result. Hence the extra $ in the error message. Make sure to define the variables as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

By default SAS strings are set to 8 characters which is too short in your case.

You can use LENGTH and INFORMAT statements to specify the length and how you want to read in the data

After INFILE and INPUT you can add your LENGTH and/or INFORMAT statements.

INFORMATs specify how a variable is formatted when it is being read (in the CSV file) while FORMATS control how a format is displayed in SAS.

You do not need to read all your variables in as character variables. You can specify the dates format and type in the

```
FILENAME IPC3data zip 'C:\Users\********\IPC3data.zip' member='tls201_appln.csv';

DATA newdata;

INFILE IPC3data DLM=';' DSD FIRSTOBS=2;



INPUT appln_id $ appln_auth $ appln_nr $ appln_kind $ appln_filing_date appln_filing_year $ appln_nr_epodoc $ appln_nr_original $ ipr_type $ internat_appln_id $ int_phase $ reg_phase $ nat_phase $ earliest_filing_date earliest_filing_year $ earliest_filing_id $ earliest_publn_date earliest_publn_year $ earliest_pat_publn_id $ granted $ docdb_family_id $ inpadoc_family_id $ docdb_family_size $ nb_citing_docdb_fam $ nb_applicants $ nb_inventors;


INFORMAT appln_filing_date earliest_filing_date earliest_publn_date anydtdte.;
FORMAT appln_filing_date earliest_filing_date earliest_publn_date DATE9.;
```

Comment: Move the INFORMAT and FORMAT to after the INPUT statement. Otherwise you are forcing the variables listed there to be the first variables in the dataset.  The INPUT statement will still work fine since where INFORMAT and FORMAT statement appear does not matter since they are not executable statements.

Comment: Dear Reeza, thanks for answering! However, I always get an error message "The format $DATE was not found or could not be loaded." on both informat and format lines...

Comment: You have to make sure the $ is removed from the input statement if you've specified a date informat.